# Flutter:How to update a UI -stateful widget from another stateful class

Tags: flutter

How do I update my UI when the value change in another stateful widget?.

I created a stateful class (Test2) which build a widget. Then in my main class, I have a list of Test2 widget. Finally, I am iterating thru the list and rendering the Test2 widget.

However, I want to update a value in one of Test2 widget and then have the main UI update accordingly.

How can I do that?

FILE:test2.dart

```
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
   Test2({this.responseId, this.message});
  final String responseId;
  final String message;
  bool strike =false;

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
      child: Text(
              widget.responseId + widget.message,
              style: (widget.strike)?TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none):TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline)
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

File :home.dart

MAIN CLASS

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      List<Test2> _counter =List();
      int cnt =0;
      @override
      void initState() { 
        super.initState();
        _counter.add(Test2(message: "message",responseId:"1"));
        _counter.add(Test2(message: "message",responseId:"2"));
        _counter.add(Test2(message: "message",responseId:"3"));
       
      }
```

In my BUILD METHOD

```
for(int i=0;i<_counter.length;i++)...[
           _counter[i]
            ],
```

BUTTON CLICK

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    for(int i=0;i<_counter.length;i++){
      if(_counter[i].responseId =="1"){
        _counter[i].strike =true;
      }
    }
     setState(() {
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ValueNotifier` to rebuild the listeners.

Decalre a `ValueNotifier<bool>` in the `Text2` class and initialize it.

```
ValueNotifier<bool> strikeNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);
```

then use `ValueListenableBuilder` to wrap the widget that you want to rebuild when value of `strike` changes.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(valueListenable: strikeNotifier, builder: (_, result, widget) => Text(...),)
```

And create a method for updating the value of `strike`, also for comparing the old and new values and update the value of `ValueNotifier` with the comparison result.

```
void updateStrike(bool value){
    var result = (strike == value);
    strike = value;
    strikeNotifier.value = result;
  }
```

So you can update the value of `strike` with `updateStrike()` in `_incrementCounter()` to notify the `Text2` widgets for rebuilding.